# Как получить даные из трех таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть три таблицы: `book`, `video`, `audio`, которые ничем не объединены. Единственное - у них у всех есть поле `created_at`. Как мне получить данные из этих трех таблиц и отсортировать по `created_at`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin таблицы ни чем не объеденны.

Comment: какие данные и в каком виде получить ? Может вам нужен обычный union

Comment: Или даже union all.

Comment: @Mike а как сортировать по create_at

Comment: @NickVolynkin а как сортировать по create_at

Comment: @Sergalas Не поверите, в самом конце запроса `order by create_at`

Comment: @Mike не поверите я пробовал вот ответ Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause'

Comment: @Sergalas А вы саму колонку created_at в списках выборки select'ов указали ? И в первом запросе union она называется именно так ?

Comment: @Mike тю точно дырявая башка спасибо пишите ответ подтвержу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a, b, c, create_at
  from book
 union all
select x, y, z, create_at
  from video
....
 order by create_at
```

После create_at обязательно должно быть выбрано во всех частях запроса. В первом select оно обязано называться именно так, как пишется в `order by`. Количество и типы колонок всех частей должны совпадать (т.е. тип колонки `a` в примере должен совпадать с типом колонки `x`).

Как вариант в сортировке можно указывать *порядковый номер* колонки в списке выборки, т.е. `order by 4`

Answer (score 1):

Если таблицы совпадают по полям, то имеет смысл их объединить. Если таблицы по полям не совпадают, то три запроса и формировать из них результирующий массив, который уже сортировать по полю created_at.

Comment: Если не совпадают по полям, то просто подбираются нужные поля в нужном порядке, что бы совпадали и делается union.

Comment: Смысл в комбинированном запросе, если у  этих таблиц только одно поле (created_at) общее?

Comment: Подготовка запроса то же время занимает. один запрос быстрее отработает чем 3, да и подбор определенных полей в самом начале сокращает трафик от БД к клиенту

Comment: Ну это еще вопрос, что быстрее сработает, union или несколько обычных select. А по поводу полей, я уже выше сказал, если у тс только это поле - created_at совпадает, смысла в таком запросе нет. Ну получит он  строки с датой создания из трех таблиц, а дальше то что?