# PostgreSQL: Добавление поля в запрос на выборку из нескольких таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Схема базы данных (posgresql):

```
Student(id, name, last_name, e_mail)
Teacher(id, name, last_name, e_mail, subject)
```

Необходимо:

Вывести все ‘`last_name`’ и ‘`name`’ всех ‘`Teacher`’ и ‘`Student`’ с полем ‘`type`‘ (student или teacher). Отсортировать в алфавитном порядке по ‘`last_name`’. Выглядеть должно так:

```
last_name   | type
            | 
Kankava     | teacher
Smith       | student
Sidorov     | teacher
Petrov      | teacher
```

Не понимаю как в `SELECT` добавить колонку `TYPE` и связать ее с таблицей?

Comment: Элементарно. Почитайте книжку "Понимание SQL" (Undershtanding SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT name, last_name, 'student' AS type FROM Student
        UNION
      SELECT name, last_name, 'teacher' AS type FROM Teacher)
   AS forexempl ORDER BY last_name;
```

Comment: Спасибо! не хватало только AS в завершении.

Comment: @TehD Тут слишком сложно написано, подзапрос вообще не нужен http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546491/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/546513#546513